# Are Casimir elements $\mathfrak {g}$-invariant?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak {g}$ be a Lie algebra equipped with a non-degenerate invariant bilinear form $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle.$ Let $r \in \mathfrak {g} \otimes \mathfrak {g}$ be a Casimir tensor with respect to $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle.$ Is $r$ $\mathfrak {g}$-invariant i.e. for all $x \in \mathfrak {g}$ do we have $\left (\text {ad}_{x} \otimes \text {id} + \text {id} \otimes \text {ad}_{x} \right ) (r) = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

If a bilinear form ⟨⋅,⋅⟩ is non-degenerate and invariant, then a Casimir tensor is an element of the tensor product of the Lie algebra that satisfies the equation (adx⊗id + id⊗adx)(r) = 0 for all x∈g.
In general,Casimir elements are g-invariant.

Comment: But Casimir tensors are in the centre of the universal enveloping algebra  $U(\mathfrak {g})$ of $\mathfrak {g}.$ From here how do you show that they are $\mathfrak {g}$-invariant?

Comment: the center of U(g) is the set of elements that are invariant under the adjoint representation of g.
Casimir tensors are defined as elements in the center of U(g), and therefore they commute with all elements in U(g), including all elements in the Lie algebra g. This means that, under the adjoint representation, the Casimir tensors are unchanged, and hence they are g-invariant.To show this rigorously, one can use the definition of the adjoint representation and the commutation relations between the Lie algebra elements to prove that the Casimir tensors are indeed invariant.

Comment: To show this rigorously, one can use the definition of the adjoint representation and the commutation relations between the Lie algebra elements to prove that the Casimir tensors are indeed invariant. This involves writing out the commutation relations between the Lie algebra elements and the Casimir tensors, and showing that they vanish.

Answer (score 0):

The Casimir's are invariant because the symmetric bilinear form you use to define them is invariant.

The condition that a bilinear form on $\mathfrak g$ is "invariant" is usually written as $b([x,y],z)+b(x,[y,z])=0$, but this is equivalent to the condition that $b$ is an invariant vector in $\text{Bil}(\mathfrak g)$ for the natural action of $\mathfrak g$ on $\text{Bil}(\mathfrak g)$ induced by the adjoint action. Indeed if $V$ is any $\mathfrak g$-representation then $\text{Bil}(V)$ is a $\mathfrak g$-representation where if $b \in \text{Bil}(V)$ then
for all $x \in \mathfrak g$ and $v_1,v_2 \in V$
$$
\begin{split}
x(b)(v_1,v_2) &= x(\tilde{b})(v_1\otimes v_2) = -\tilde{b}\big(x(v_1\otimes v_2)\big)\\
& = -\tilde{b}\big(x(v_1)\otimes v_2 + v_1\otimes x(v_2)\big) \\
&= -b(x(v_1),v_2) - b(v_1,x(v_2).
\end{split}
$$
Thus $b$ is invariant if, for all $x\in \mathfrak g$ and $v_1,v_2\in V$ we have $b(x(v_1),v_2)+b(v_1,x(v_2))=0$. (Note that if $b$ is nondegenerate, this is equivalent to the condition that $\mathfrak g$ acts by skew-adjoint operators on $(V,b)$.)

When $V=(\mathfrak g, \text{ad})$, we can rewrite this condition as follows:

$$
\begin{split}
b \in \text{Bil}(\mathfrak g)^{\mathfrak g} &\iff
&b(\text{ad}(y)(x),z) + b(x,\text{ad}(y)(z)) =0, \quad \forall x,y,z \in \mathfrak g \\
&\iff &b([y,x],z)+b(x,[y,z]) =0 \quad \forall x,y,z \in \mathfrak g \\\
&\iff &b([x,y],z) = b(x,[y,z])\quad \forall x,y,z \in \mathfrak g.
\end{split}
$$

Next note that there is a canonical identification

$$
\text{Bil}(V) \cong (V\otimes V)^* = \text{Hom}_{\mathsf k}(V\otimes V, \mathsf k) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathsf k}(V,\text{Hom}_{\mathsf k}(V,\mathsf k)) = \text{Hom}_{\mathsf k}(V,V^*)
$$

given by $b \mapsto \theta_b$, where if $v_1\in V$, then $\theta_b(v_1)$ is given by $\theta_b(v_1)(v_2) = b(v_1,v_2)$ for all $v_2 \in V$. The map $b \mapsto \theta_b$ is clearly an isomorphism with inverse $\phi \mapsto b_{\phi}$ given by $b_{\phi}(v_1,v_2) = \phi(v_1)(v_2)$, and if $V$ is a $\mathfrak g$-representation, then it is easy to see that this identification is an isomorphism of $\mathfrak g$-representations. Moreover, by definition $b$ is nondegenerate if and only if $\theta_b$ is injective, which, when $V$ is finite-dimensional, is equivalent to $\theta_b$ being an isomorphism.
Thus if $b \in \text{Bil}(\mathfrak g)$ is a nondegenerate invariant bilinear form on $\mathfrak g$ the associated map $\theta_b \colon \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g^*$ is an isomorphism of $\mathfrak g$-representations.

Now for vector space $V$ we have a canonical injective linear map

$$
m\colon V^*\otimes V^*\to (V\otimes V)^*,  \quad m(f_1\otimes f_2) =f_1.f_2 \quad \forall f_1,f_2 \in V^*
$$
where $(f_1.f_2)(v_1,v_2) = f_1(v_1).f_2(v_2)$ for all $v_1,v_2 \in V$. Comparing dimensions we see that if $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $m$ is an isomorphism.

Putting all of this together, if $\mathfrak g$ is finite-dimensional and $b$ is a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form, we may define

$$
C_b = (\theta_b^{-1}\otimes \theta_b^{-1})\circ m^{-1}(b)\in \mathfrak g \otimes \mathfrak g,
$$
and since $b$ is invariant, and $\theta_b$ is a $\mathfrak g$-homomorphism, it follows that $C_b$ is invariant.

To make this more explicit, suppose that $\{x_i:1\leq i \leq n\}$ and $\{y_j:1 \leq j \leq n\}$ are bases of $\mathfrak g$ dual with respect to $b$ (so that $b(x_i,y_j) = \delta_{ij}$). Then if $\{\delta_i:1\leq i\leq n\}$ and $\{\eta_j:1\leq j\leq n\}$ are the bases of $\mathfrak g^*$ dual to $\{x_i:1\leq i\leq n\}$ and $\{y_j:1\leq j\leq n\}$, we have $m(\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i\otimes \eta_i) = b$. Moreover, $\theta_b(x_i)(y_j) = b(x_i,y_j) = \delta_{ij}$, and so $\theta_b(x_i) = \eta_i$, and similarly $\theta_b(y_j) = \delta_j$. It follows that $C_b = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\otimes x_i$.

For example, for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$, the trace form $t(x,y) = \text{tr}(xy)$ is a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form (assuming $\text{char}(\mathsf k)\neq 2)$, and it is easy to compute that $t(e,f)=1$, $t(h,h) =2$, and all other pairings of the standard basis $\{e=E_{12},f= E_{21},h= E_{11}-E_{22}\}$ are zero. It follows that the dual basis to $\{e,h,f\}$ is $\{f,\frac{1}{2}h,e\}$ and hence

$$
C_t = e\otimes f + f\otimes e + \frac{1}{2} h\otimes h.
$$